# How can I connect nested rows in - recursion problem in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

I want to designate KEY for two columns ID and PARAM. 
All rows with the same ID should have the same KEY.
Rows are connected by both columns that means ID=1 is connected with ID=2 by PARAM=A. ID=2 is connected with ID=3 by PARAM=D, and with ID=4 by PARAM=D also. ID=5 is connected with ID=4 by PARAM=W. ... ID=8 is connected with ID=4 by PARAM=AA

Here are sample input data, real data are more nested

```
ID   PARAM  KEY Excepted result 
1    A      1-A
1    C      1-A
2    A      1-A
2    C      1-A
2    D      1-A
3    D      1-A
4    AA     1-A
4    D      1-A
4    K      1-A
4    T      1-A
4    W      1-A
4    Z      1-A
5    W      1-A
6    W      1-A
7    T      1-A
8    AA     1-A
10   FF     10-FF
15   G      15-G
99   FF     10-FF
```

I tried with some group by operations, min(), max() but i can't get excepted results.
Do You have any suggestions how can I receive column KEY with SQL on Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this, but to me it looks like a problem best solved with CONNECT BY.

I created a table called "mytable" with your sample data and wrote an example query that returns the expected results.

Outline:

- We start from any row and connect to another row based on either the ID or PARAM being the same.
- Using the NOCYCLE keyword prevents loops.
- The CONNECT_BY_ROOT function selects a value from the row that we started at.
- The inner query returns more rows than we want, though. For instance, [4, D] has [3, D] as a "root", but we want to trace it back as far as possible, to [1, A].
- So in order to reduce the rows, we use the row_number() analytic function to number each "root" for a given id/param pair.
- Then we select only the results where the row number (r1) is equal to one.
- And finally the results are sorted by the id and param values.

```
select id, param, rootid||'-'||rootparam as "Expected result" from (
select  row_number() over (partition by id, param order by rootid, rootparam) r1,
    rootid, rootparam, id, param from (
        select connect_by_root(id) rootid, connect_by_root(param) rootparam,
            id, param
        from mytable
        connect by nocycle (prior param =param and prior id <> id)
                        or (prior id = id and prior param <> param)
        order by connect_by_root(id), connect_by_root(param)
    )
) where r1 = 1
order by to_number(id), param
```

*Disclaimer: This is an example for informational purposes and not intended to be optimal or optimized SQL. It is not appropriate to use* as is *for your production application or homework assignment. Use EXPLAIN PLAN to see if the optimizer is being reasonable and if you have large amounts of data and are concerned about speed, measure the time your alternative queries take rather than guessing what is faster.*

Here is the initialization for the test data:

```
create table mytable as
select '1' ID,'A' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '1' ID,'C' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '2' ID,'A' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '2' ID,'C' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '2' ID,'D' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '3' ID,'D' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'AA' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'D' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'K' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'T' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'W' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '4' ID,'Z' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '5' ID,'W' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '6' ID,'W' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '7' ID,'T' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '8' ID,'AA' PARAM from dual -- 1-A
union all select '10' ID,'FF' PARAM from dual -- 10-FF
union all select '15' ID,'G' PARAM from dual -- 15-G
union all select '99' ID,'FF' PARAM from dual -- 10-FF
```